# mysql procedure not deleting data

Tags: mysql

I have a simple mysql procedure below to delete data from a table based on an argument passed.
I am getting foreign constraint failed exception as the dependent data is not deleted.
I am forming a list of IDs to delete as i want to avoid full table scan on the table
when using sub queries.
Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `deleteService`(IN serviceID LONG)
BEGIN
    DECLARE rpslist varchar(512) DEFAULT "";
        DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE rpsid varchar(512) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE rpsidcursor 
        CURSOR FOR 
              select id from rpsa where so_id in (select id from rpso where rps_id = serviceID);
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
 
        OPEN rpsidcursor; //fetch ids to delete
        getRPSId: LOOP       
            FETCH rpsidcursor INTO rpsid;
            IF finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE getRPSId;
            END IF;
        SET rpsid = concat("'",rpsid,"'"); -- form concatenated string of IDs
        SET rpslist = CONCAT(rpsid,",",rpslist);
        END LOOP getRPSId;
        CLOSE rpsidcursor;
        SET rpslist = substring(rpslist,1,length(rpslist) -1); -- remove last comma
        DELETE from uach where rpsa_id in (rpslist); -- delete dependent data . forming the list to hit index

    -- this statement fails bcos the delete above did not work and there is foreign constraint
        DELETE from rpsa where rpselectedso_id in (select id from rpselectedso where rpaxnservice_id = serviceID); 
END
```

Comment: Why are you using a cursor and concatenating ID's (I'm assuming integer types) to a string? Why can't you just put your ID's into a temp table and use that in  your delete statement? If you are trying to avoid a table scan, then your indexes are wrong.

Comment: `WHERE .. IN (...)` needs a list of string literals (many arguments-literals separated by comma), whereas `rpslist` is ONE string literal with CSV. Use `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(rpsa_id, rpslist)` instead.

Comment: i have tried both of the above and in both cases it does full table scan. the index is correctly defined on the id rpsa_id column . works locally not in prod where there are million plus rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a CSV string variable like `IN (variable)` won't work because MySQL will see the variable as a single element and not multiple ids.
If you want to do such a thing, you should use dynamic queries.

Comment: can you please share an article or an example to do this. i want each of the id to be treated as id and not as a string variable. thank u so much

Comment: figured out with dynamic queries. thank u for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use direct queries:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `deleteService`(IN serviceID LONG)
BEGIN

delete
from uach 
  join rpsa on rpsa.id=uach.rpsa_id
  join rpso on rpso.id=rpsa.so_id
where rpso.rps_id=serviceID;

delete 
from rpsa 
  join rpselectedso on rpselectedso.id=rpsa.rpselectedso_id
where rpselectedso.rpaxnservice_id=serviceID;

END
```

Comment: this was my first choice. i have an explicit index on rpsa_id on uach table but explain on that query does a full table scan. that table in production has million+ rows.

Comment: You can also use joins